# IE Fails to Show Feed with the Error: Internet Explorer does not support feeds with DTDs

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed, xml-validation

When I access the page of the following PHP code in IE, IE produces the error, "Internet Explorer does not support feeds with DTDs. This feed contains a DTD (Document Type Definition). ... ... DTDs are used to define a structure of a webpage. Internet Explorer does not support DTDs in feeds."

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
?>          
<!DOCTYPE doctypeName [
   <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>                  
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>Sample Feed</title>
    <link>http://google.com</link>
    <description>This is a test</description>   
        <item>
            <title>Item</title>
            <description>This is the item.&nbsp;&nbsp;</description>
        </item>
</channel>      
</rss>
```

I suspect this part is the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE doctypeName [
   <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
```

But if I remove it, I get this error instead:

> Reference to undefined entity 'nbsp'.
>   Line: 10 Character: 36
>
> This is the item.

So it is necessary to allow `&nbsp;` in the description tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need `&nbsp;` in the first place? It's not valid XML. If you need it inside your content, it's HTML content and you should put it in `CDATA` tags

Comment: @Pekka `Why do you need &nbsp; in the first place?` - It is an automatically generated content-feed in my actual program. So it gets inserted inevitably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is not valid XML. Using a DTD to make it valid is a terrible workaround.

If you need it in your content, that content is really HTML; in that case, you should either

- wrap it in [CDATA tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) or
- escape the ampersands into `&amp;`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398571/html-inside-xml-should-i-use-cdata-or-encode-the-html) gives an overview over which method is better. Quentin's answer also contains another solution, using a XML library to create the markup. It may be overkill for your specific example, but it usually the best way to go.

Comment: Thank you. `CDATA` seems to be the way to go.