# Skipping Html Content in Tag attributes

Tags: java, saxparser

I am using SAX Parser to parse following piece of data with "Description" attribute containing  HTML content . But I am getting error "The value of attribute "Description" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character".

How to make SAX Parser ignore this tag while XML Processing?

```
<Thread ThreadID="22" Title="google"
                    Description="<a href="http://google.com/">http://google.com/</a>"
                    DisplayName="Sam" LoginID="hjaja" UserEmailID="abx@ers"
                    UserSapCode="12345"
                    IsAnonymous="Yes" CreatedDate="2015-04-29T21:56:04.943" ReplyCount="0"
                    ViewCount="0" PopularityPoints="0" LastUpdatedBy="" LastPostDate="" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to either escape the HTML and its XML control characters (`<`, `>`, and `"`) in the Description, or not include it, since it's breaking the XML structure by including XML-like data. The parser is seeing `Description="<a href="` as the entire attribute, then complaining at you because there's a `<` in `"<a href="`.

Comment: The XML is broken anyways. YOu shouldn't try to get a parser to "ignore" broken xml - you should be fixing whatever's producing the bad xml in the first place. e.g. you're asking "how do I pry out these bullets inside me" instead of "how do I stop getting shot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really thing that you should take a look at this post ([HTML code inside XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398571/html-inside-xml-should-i-use-cdata-or-encode-the-html)) to see how other people recommended to tackle such problem.

Answer (score 0):

No XML parser can parse this data as the data do not comply the xml format. Please refer [XML specifications](http://www.w3.org/XML/).

There are two ways you can solve this:

1. Change the source format

Change the source to create the proper XML. You can include HTMLs by escaping the characters using these:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

2. Change the target algo

Second is by creating your own parsing algorithm for you case.

Usually answer is always the the first one.