# Preserve HTML Tags in XML Child Node Values While Using XMLSerializer

Tags: javascript, html, xml, blob, domparser

I am working with the blob API in the latest Chrome and would like to have the following XML DOM added to a new empty object URL:

```
<root>
  <Title>
   <H1>A Title</H1>
   <H2>A Subtitle</H2>
   Some text or other elements<BR/>
  </Title>
</root>
```

This piece of XML is selected by the user with their mouse from a content editable DIV. Then I convert that selection into an XML DOM like so:

```
var n_parser = new DOMParser; //new parser
var small_xml_string = "<root>" + window.getSelection().toString() + "</root>"; //add a root node
var small_xml_obj = n_parser.parseFromString(small_xml_string.replace(/\n/g, ""), "text/xml"); //convert user selection to string then to an XML DOM while removing some expected newlines below the selection
```

The DOMParser however fails to convert any nodes to XML that would have any HTML tags in them, resulting in the following DOM:

```
<root>
  </Title>
</root>
```

I've tried escaping the the HTML entities but the parser still behaves the same. This was the code I created to try and deal with entities:

```
var unencoded_title =
  small_xml_string.toString().substring(
    small_xml_string.toString().indexOf("<Title>") + 7,
    small_xml_string.toString().indexOf("</Title>")
    );//Find the string between the title tags
var encoded_title_lt = unencoded_title.replace(/</g, "&lt;");//replace the "<" with "&lt;"
var encoded_title = encoded_title_lt.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");//replace the ">" with "&gt;"
xml_dom.getElementsByTagName("Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = encoded_title //Add the encoded string to the node, replacing what's there
```

Note that "xml_dom" is a ready DOM that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <Title>Example
    </Title>
</root>
```

The resulting DOM though is exactly the same as if I'd passed the HTML tags in.
Users will be adding HTML tags like line breaks and superscript to the input. How can I process HTML tags in the user input, ready to pass to the blob api?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly the content of `window.getSelection().toString()` is supposed to be now? You said the user had selected the whole(?) XML you have shown, but then I don't see how it would make sense that you wrap an _additional_ `root` around it.

Comment: And in which HTML version do you put `H2` or `BR` elements into a `Title` element? Isn't `title` a plain text child of `head` only?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I guess it is XML, that can _contain_ HTML tags, but it is not meant to _be_ HTML on its own.

Comment: But "content editable DIV" doesn't give you XML, it allows editing HTML.

Comment: The string value `<root><Title><H1>A Title</H1><H2>A Subtitle</H2>Some text or other elements<BR/></Title></root>` parses absolutely fine for me in Chrome, and gives exactly the result one would expect - https://jsfiddle.net/53a6bed0/ Really not sure what the issue actually is supposed to be here.

Comment: @MartinHonnen yeah, true. Maybe that's the actual root, no pun intended, of the problem here - that reading that selection did not return the expected result to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for answering so quickly. 

The reason I added a root node is because without a containing node the blob api throws an error saying there is no content after line number xx.

Also, the XML has a <Title><Title> node, which can contain multiple other HTML tags. The browser rendering of the XML markup isn't the issue. The issue is that the DOMParser doesn't process nodes that contain HTML tags.

What you said here: "I guess it is XML, that can contain HTML tags, but it is not meant to be HTML on its own." <- This is correct.

Comment: _"The issue is that the DOMParser doesn't process nodes that contain HTML tags"_ - you _say_ that, but I have no idea what it is actually supposed to mean. Explain either what is wrong with the result the fiddle I have shown produces - or explain how your real scenario actually significantly differs from what happens in there.

Comment: @CBroe The fiddle doesn't work for me. Damn, I hope it isn't browser related. In any case, I'll try to further explain:

User has this structure in a contenteditable div:
<Title></Title>

They then add their own tags and content as I showed in the example above. 

The input is then processed as above. I want the DOMParser to create an XML DOM ready to be serialized and passed to the blob API. It works perfectly if there aren't any HTML tags in there.

Comment: Seems this would be made much simpler if you used [`<![CDATA[]]>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1398976/542251)

Comment: @Liam thanks ofr replying. Unfortunately, I can't use CDATA for this as the system that will process the resulting XML will not process it properly.

Comment: Well then that system is wrong. CData is valid XML. All XML parsers should handle it correctly

Comment: As in it will not ingest the XML as having valid HTML within the input because it isn't set up that way. The system is a multimillion pound platform and is NOT wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in `getSelection().toString()` this will return the text content of the actual selection. What you want is [`Range.cloneContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/cloneContents), which gets a copy of the DOM structure:

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = evt => {
const sel = getSelection();
const range = sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt(0);
const content = range.cloneContents?.();
const xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<root>
  <Title/>
</root>`, "text/xml");
xml.querySelector("Title").append(content||"");
console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml));
};
```

```html
Select the content below:
<H1>A Title</H1>
<H2>A Subtitle</H2>
Some text or other elements<BR/>
<button>log</button>
```